# wrong css media syntax

Tags: css, media

What is wrong here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='index-02.css'
      media="screen and (min-width: 481px and max-width:959px)">
```

Validating the code on [this page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) I got an error:

> Error: Bad value screen and (min-width: 481px and max-width:959px) for attribute media on element link: Expected whitespace or ) but saw a instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off.  Each expression needs to be contained within parentheses:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='index-02.css'
      media="screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:959px)">
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

> Parentheses are required around expressions; failing to use them is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

screen and (min-width: 481px)and(max-width: 959px)